# Modal display different data for different buttons used to open it

Tags: adminhtml, magento2.4, uicomponent, modal-popup

A Magento admin feature that I am developing consists of adding an array of Foo objects to Products. Each Foo is configured by clicking on a "Configure Foo" button, which opens a modal.

[image]

However, the modal opened is currently shared across Foo objects. If I configure one Foo, then closing the modal, then press "Configure Foo" for another object, then the same configuration opens.

**How can I have separate configurations for each Foo?**

The "Configure Foo" button is added via the following array in a Modifier's `modifyMeta()` method:

```
'config' => [
    'title' => __('Configure Foo'),
    'formElement' => Container::NAME,
    'componentType' => Container::NAME,
    'component' => 'Magento_Ui/js/form/components/button',
    'actions' => [
        [
            'targetName' => 'ns=product_form, index=foos_modal',
            'actionName' => 'openModal',
        ],
    ],
    'sortOrder' => $sort_order,
],
```

For prototyping, an example Modifier that will output such an array of Foo objects on a Product is [pasted here](https://pastebin.com/KBdX5SBL).

Comment: Hi @dotancohen could you add steps to add that fieldset, fields, popup,... like your screenshot into your post to help us build test data quickly?

Comment: @TuVan Sure thing, I've pasted it here: https://pastebin.com/z5Cq9uxS

Comment: The code in `modifyMeta` method does not have enough to make the fieldset grid container show. Could you upload your custom module in a zip file?

Comment: @TuVan I've updated the paste to put in the entire `modifyData()` and `modifyMeta()` methods. If you come up with a solution, I'll happily reopen the bounty to reward it to you. The new paste is [here](https://pastebin.com/KBdX5SBL).

Comment: I'm now able to reproduce your issue, I'll take a look :)